# How to do a simple cross column classification in Python (Pandas/Numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, grouping, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
A = pd.DataFrame([['Cat_1', 'Cat_1', 'Cat_2'], ['Cat_1', 'Cat_2', 'Cat_2'], ['Cat_2', 'Cat_2', 
                   'Cat_2'], ['Cat_1', 'Cat_1', 'Cat_1'], ['Cat_2', 'Cat_1', 'Cat_2']],
                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I would like to count and summarize in a table the different occurring combinations of pairs between two. In this example, for the columns A and B, this would be the output.

```
                 B
 A       'Cat_1'  'Cat_2'
'Cat_1'     2        1
'Cat_2'     1        1
```

I thought I could do this bay using, and it seems I get the result, but I don't think is the appropriated way to do it....

```
A.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg([len])

Out[126]: 
               C
              len
A     B         
Cat_1 Cat_1    2
      Cat_2    1
Cat_2 Cat_1    1
      Cat_2    1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is is what `pd.crosstab` (short for "cross-tabulation", I think) does:

```
pd.crosstab(A['A'], A['B'])
Out[5]: 
B      Cat_1  Cat_2
A                  
Cat_1      2      1
Cat_2      1      1
```